# ES6 Modules (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

Under ES6, on the client-side, I presume stuff defined outside of a function will continue to pollute the global scope. In ES5 I would typically register a bunch of types in a root  "namespace object" at application initialisation time, like so:

```
(function (namespace) {
    function MyConstructor() {
    }

    namespace.MyConstructor = MyConstructor;
}(applicationNamespace));
```

I could then later on, refer to my types, as follows:

```
var o = new applicationNamespace.MyConstructor();
```

Easy enough.

In ES6, how do I achieve the same effect? I presume I still need to wrap everything in my file in an IIFE to protect against polluting the global scope?

```
(function() {
  function MyConstructor() {
  }

  export MyConstructor; // Will this make the constructor function globally visible?
}())
```

Most of the examples online appear to be for Node.js where the contents of a file lack the IIFE, but on the client-side wouldn't this cause pollution of the global scope, even in ES6?

Or does the presence of the `export` keyword modify the scoping behavior?

Finally, how can I achieve semantic namespacing with ES6 modules. Something like `myapp.utils.MyConstructor`?

Comment: I thought `export` was to do with when you include script files, i.e. a `var foo;` identifier will only be available to code from that `<script>` unless you `export var foo;`? Then you would `import 'foo' as bar;` in some other piece of code if you wanted it. (http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/08/es6-modules but I'm not certain about this as it looks like it would break a lot of earlier _JavaScript_)

Answer (score 0):

Exports are not going to pollute global namespace as they need to be imported.

As an example in ES6 you could write:

```
export let a = 1;
```

The equivalent ES5 would be:

```
var a = 1;
module.exports = { a : a };
```

In another file, to consume the exported variable in ES6:

```
import { a } from './other-file';
console.log(a); // 1
```

that would be roughly equivalent to the following ES5:

```
var a = require('other-file').a;
console.log(a); // 1
```

Variables will be scoped per file, and bundlers will usually wrap each file in a function when concatenating.

To create a namespace in ES6

```
// class-file.js
export default () => {
  console.log('constructor called');
};

// namespace.js
import A from './class-file';
export default {
  A
};

// app.js
import namespace from './namespace';
let a = new namespace.A(); // constructor called
```